# FormatException was unhandled float.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, exception, formatting

I have FormatException problem. Here is the code. How can I change this to compile this piece of code ?

```
private Tacka[] load() 
{
   ArrayList dataX = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList dataY = new ArrayList();

   var citac = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\K-Means\s1.csv"));
   var linija = citac.ReadLine();

   if (linija.StartsWith("%") || linija.StartsWith("@") || linija.StartsWith("/") || linija.Length == 0)
   {

   }
   else 
   {
       var values = linija.Split(' ');
       dataX.Add(values[0]);
       dataY.Add(values[1]);
   }
   Tacka[] nizTacaka = new Tacka[dataX.Count];
   //List<Tacka> tacka = new List<Tacka>();
   for (int i = 0; i < dataX.Count; i++)
   {
       //tacka.Add(new Tacka(float.Parse(dataX[i].ToString()), float.Parse(dataY[i].ToString())));
       nizTacaka[i] = new Tacka(float.Parse(dataX[i].ToString()), float.Parse(dataY[i].ToString()));
   }

   return nizTacaka;
}
```

Comment: I hope it was because of `float.Parse` failed to convert the `dataX[i].ToString()` and/or `dataY[i].ToString()`

Comment: Line: nizTacaka[i] = new Tacka(float.Parse(dataX[i].toString()), float.Parse(dataY[i].ToString()));

Comment: dataX[i] and dataY[i] are values from txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) that is thrown when the format of an argument is
>   invalid, or when a composite format string is not well formed.

Here in your case it Was thrown because Either `dataX[i].ToString()` and/or `dataY[i].ToString()` is not convertible to a float value(may be it is `null`,`Empty`, or characters other than number). So you can use `TryParse` to check the conversion status, and Create the object only when the conversion is fine. Try the following code:

```
float xValue, yValue;
for (int i = 0; i < dataX.Count; i++)
{
    if (float.TryParse(dataX[i].ToString(),out xValue) && float.TryParse(dataY[i].ToString(),out yValue))
    {
          nizTacaka[i] = new Tacka(xValue, yValue);
    }
    else
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Conversion failed");
    }

}
```